# Trying To Play Random Song at Random Time (To Study For Music Final :))

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, audio

> Here are the files. Right now I keep getting a message from the alert that the track variable is undefined. It seems like the PHP works because if i go straight to the php link, and manually type in the GET variable, i get the song returned. Also, I am looking for a way to get a random 10 second clip of a song (like how my music teacher tests us). The way I thought of is to divide the duration by 10 and multiply it by a random number, and then use a setineterval to see if the currenttime() is 10 seconds more that the initial audio time.

```
//index.php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Music Final Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <audio src="" id="player"></audio>
    <button id="change_track">Play A Different Track</button>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//script.js
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var changeTrack = document.getElementById("change_track");
var previousNumber = null;
var timeStart = null;

function loadTrack(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    if(randomNumber != 0 && randomNumber != previousNumber){
        previousNumber = randomNumber;
    }else{
        randomNumber = 1;
    }
    var track = $().get("generate_song.php?track_number=" + randomNumber);
    player.src = track;
    player.load();
    // player.currentTime() = (player.duration/10) * Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    player.play();
    alert(track);
}

window.addEventListener("load", loadTrack);
changeTrack.addEventListener("click",loadTrack);

//generate_song.php
$directory = "Audio_Files";
$files = scandir($directory);
$requested_song = $_GET["track_number"];

echo $files[$requested_song + 1]."<br/>";
```

Comment: well that's a great way to procrastinate.

Comment: Lol the test is on Friday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

player.currentTime is property, not a function so it should be:

```
player.currentTime = (player.duration/10) * Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
```

For interval part I would add interval and check if song is paused:

```
    function loadTrack(){
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
        if(randomNumber != 0 && randomNumber != previousNumber){
            previousNumber = randomNumber;
        }else{
            randomNumber = 1;
        }
        var track = $().get("generate_song.php?track_number=" + randomNumber);
        player.src = track;
        player.load();
        player.currentTime = (player.duration/10) * Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
        player.play();
        playTenSeconds = setInterval(function(){
            if(player.paused === false){
                player.pause();
                alert(track);
                clearInterval(playTenSeconds);
            }else{
                player.play();
            }
        }, 10);
    }
```